# How do I open up a certain TabPage based on data in a ListView?

Tags: vb.net, listview, tabcontrol, tabpage

I have created 2 forms: `Form1` and `Form2`. `Form1` contains my `TabControl` which has 5 `TabPages`. There are 5 `TabPages`: 'Special Incident Entry', 'Accident Incident Entry', 'General Incident Entry', 'Injury Incident Entry', and 'Workplace Violent Incident Entry'.

My `Form2` contains a `ListView`. I created a column header named "Entry Type". Now there are 5 entry types: 'Special Incident Entry', 'Accident Incident Entry', 'General Incident Entry', 'Injury Incident Entry', and 'Workplace Violent Incident Entry'. What I'm trying to accomplish is this:

When the user double clicks on any item in the `ListView`, based on what is stated under the column "Entry Type" for that item, the corresponding `TabPage` opens containing form controls.

I've tried `Form1.TabControl1.SelectedIndex = 1` and that opens up the `TabPage` with  the index 1. How do I get the 'Entry Type' input from the `ListView` on `Form2` then open the respective `TabPage` on `Form1`? Ive added test data into my `ListView` to try  and figure it out.

Comment: Add a constructor to `Form2` that has a parameter for entry type and use that to set the `SelectedIndex` of the `TabControl`.  In `Form1`, when you create a `Form2` instance, pass the appropriate value to the constructor.

Comment: You can create a Public method in `Form1` (say: `Public sub SetTabControlPage(ThisPage as integer)  TabControl1.SelectedIndex = ThisPage  End Sub`. In `Form2` you can access this method, since it's Public (and you can also access the `Form1` default instance), and call it from the appropriate `ListView` event handler (`Click`, maybe): `Form1.SetTabControlPage([SomeIntegerValue])`. `[SomeIntegerValue]` could be the `SelectedIndexes[0]` value or another value contained in the `SelectedItems[0]` Item.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the double click event and getting the value in the appropriate SubItem. This value is then used in the Select Case to select the correct tab.

```
Private Sub ListView1_DoubleClick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ListView1.DoubleClick
        'Use whatever SubItem index is the appropriate column
        Dim strTabName As String = ListView1.SelectedItems(0).SubItems(0).Text
        Select Case strTabName
            Case "Special Incident Entry"
                Form1.TabControl1.SelectedIndex = 0
            Case "Accident Incident Entry"
                Form1.TabControl1.SelectedIndex = 1
            Case "General Incident Entry"
                Form1.TabControl1.SelectedIndex = 2
            Case "Injury Incident Entry"
                Form1.TabControl1.SelectedIndex = 3
            Case "Workplace Violent Incident Entry"
                Form1.TabControl1.SelectedIndex = 4
            Case Else
                MessageBox.Show("Please try double clicking again.")
        End Select
    End Sub
```

Comment: I believe that would be SubItem(1). Did you change my code to reflect that?

Comment: My apologies @Mary I changed the SubItems(0) to (2). Thank you for your help!